# Parsing XML File in JS

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file in JS,The Below XML contains parent & child elements as given below

**MY XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
<program name="Vishal">
    <computation type="student">
        <module type="a1">              
            <modPath>aaa</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>aaaaaaaa</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>aaaa</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a2">              
            <modPath>xxxx</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>tttttt</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>yyyy</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a3">
            <modPath>bbbbbbbbbb</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>bbbbbbbbbb</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>bbbbbbbb</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a4">
            <modPath>cccc</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>cccccc</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>ccccccc</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a5">
            <modPath>ddddddd</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>ddddddddddddd</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>dddddddddd</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a6">
            <modPath>eeee</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>eee</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>eee</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a7">
            <modPath>ffff</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>ffff</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>fffff</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="a8">
            <modPath>ggggggg</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>ggggggg</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>ggggggg</modSchematic>
        </module>
    </computation>
    <computation type="Employee">
        <module type="b1">              
            <modPath>lllll</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>llllll</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>lllll</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="b2">              
            <modPath>mmmmmmmmm</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>mmmmmmmm</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>mmmmmm</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="b3">
            <modPath>nnnn</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>nnnnnn</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>nnnn</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="b4">
            <modPath>oooooo</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>ooooooo</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>oooooooooooo</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="b5">
            <modPath>pppppppppp</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>ppppppppppp</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>ppppppppppp</modSchematic>
        </module>
        <module type="b6">
            <modPath>qqqqqqqqq</modPath>
            <modInputTemplate>qqqqqqqqqq</modInputTemplate>
            <modSchematic>qqqqqqqqqqq</modSchematic>
        </module>           
    </computation>      
</program>
<program name="Rakesh">
.......
.......
.......
</program>
<program name="Praveen">
.......
.......
.......
</program>
</root>
```

**JavaScript File**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Read XML in Microsoft Browsers</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    function loadxml()
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = readXML;
        xmlDoc.load("writers.xml");
    }

    function readXML()
    {
        if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4){
            myFunction(xmlDoc);
        }
        function myFunction(xml) {
            var x, i, txt;
            txt = "";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("module");

            for( i = 0; i < x[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
                txt += x[0].childNodes[i].nodeName + ": " + x[0].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadxml()">
    <p id="demo">Write output of loadxml()</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Out put what I am getting is only a1 contetnt:

```
aaa

aaaaaaaa

aaaa
```

I want for all the childs (a1 to a8)

**Requirement:**

1)If I pass a parent attribute value like 'name=Vishal",Then I should get all its child nodes as follows

```
<computation type="student">
    <module type="a1">              
        <modPath>aaa</modPath>
        <modInputTemplate>aaaaaaaa</modInputTemplate>
        <modSchematic>aaaa</modSchematic>
    </module>
    <module type="a2">              
        <modPath>xxxx</modPath>
        <modInputTemplate>tttttt</modInputTemplate>
        <modSchematic>yyyy</modSchematic>
    </module>
    .
    .
    .
</computation>
```

2)Similarly if I pass the attribute as type="student",Then I should get all its child nodes, as given below

```
    <module type="a1">              
        <modPath>aaa</modPath>
        <modInputTemplate>aaaaaaaa</modInputTemplate>
        <modSchematic>aaaa</modSchematic>
    </module>
    <module type="a2">              
        <modPath>xxxx</modPath>
        <modInputTemplate>tttttt</modInputTemplate>
        <modSchematic>yyyy</modSchematic>
    </module>
    .
    .
    .
    <module type="a8">
        <modPath>ggggggg</modPath>
        <modInputTemplate>ggggggg</modInputTemplate>
        <modSchematic>ggggggg</modSchematic>
    </module>
```

whats the logic to print above nodes by passing the attribute values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the DOMParser. Here is an example.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = '<your xml>';
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
// Now, you can simply query the xml document as you would the DOM...
var modules = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('module');
var vishalModules = xmlDoc.querySelector('[name="Vishal"] module');
```

Here is a fiddle that fills both of your requirements:

https://jsfiddle.net/bcezsuc8/

**UPDATE**

Here is another fiddle that gets all of the children under type student. Note that it does not use ActiveX. You can just use the DOMParser which is native javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/bcezsuc8/3/

Comment: I will try that ,Do you have any link for that

Comment: Here is a link to the API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser Give me a minute and I will add a fiddle.

Comment: HI,I have added the JS file,Please check & also wriiten the o/p

Comment: @Ram if my answer has helped you please mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: I went for different approach it worked..Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(xml);
$('computation[type=student]'); // your second exmaple
```

You can learn other method in it's documents.

Comment: Everything for xml is built directly into browsers, I would say use what is there. Just my opinion on using a library for something like this.

Comment: I can not use Jquery,I am using JavaScript

Comment: that won't work if the XML tags have any overlap with HTML tags with special behaviors, like RSS's `<title>` for example.